# How to validate image size of a CloudinaryField in Django model

Tags: image, validation, django-models, cloudinary

I'm relatively new to django...
I have an CloudinaryField in my django model that allows an image to be uploaded on the django admin panel. However I want to add validators to this to check the file size.

```
class NewsCard(models.Model):
    card_image = CloudinaryField('image', default='card_placeholder')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    summary = models.TextField(blank=True, max_length=500)
    url = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I know I can add validators as per the django docs and can see how to do this for an ImageField, but I'm unsure how to apply checks to a CloudinaryField. I've read through their docs and I feel like the answer may involve their [Transformations](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/transformations_on_upload) and/or their [Upload Presets](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_presets). I feel like I'm a bit out of my depth though as I don't know how to apply this to my django model.

Any advice appreciated!

Comment: You may define the custom validation object based on the definition of the `CloudinaryField` object [as defined in this documentation](https://github.com/cloudinary/pycloudinary/blob/c5160e76ddc1b150e1248eaf4a828d7ee0c26677/cloudinary/models.py#L39). You may also check some sample tests as [described in this documentation](https://github.com/cloudinary/pycloudinary/blob/6a2f5894d715e441c6b955bc62c3fc1e74e0d8ae/django_tests/test_cloudinaryField.py)